# How to make the jitter point centered using ggplot2？

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to recreate a multiple dot plot like the figure below.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9jqguesqd5gdm99/jitter%20plot.png

Both **geom_dotplot** and **position_jitter** in ggplot2 have been tried. But neither of these two commands could make it.

The figure created by position_jitter is quite similar, but there are also some differences. The point created by position_jitter seems too scattered, compared to the figure mentioned above.

This is the figure I could make so far.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/athsgkjjrlwr15k/figure.png?dl=0
e.g.

```
value<-c(141573,  262616,   66773.8,    93032.2,    55528.8,    113125, 252954, 275581, 207854, 183300, 292946, 171510, 343565, 214436, 295871, 187196, 207352, 180356, 158110, 241769, 180112, 194007, 529168, 229267, 344257, 337311, 255109, 307389, 416108, 405033, 292260, 354368, 416811, 330420, 353017, 333997, 389285, 289870, 289224, 401641, 206481, 367379)
group<-factor(c(1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2))
quantile<-boxplot(value~group)
line<-quantile$stats
library(ggplot2)
gg<-ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x=group,y=value,color=group,fill=group),position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.3,dodge.width=0.7),size=4)+
geom_path(aes(x=c(0.8,1.2),y=c(line[3,1],line[3,1])),size=1)+geom_path(aes(x=c(1.8,2.2),y=c(line[3,2],line[3,2])),size=1)+geom_path(aes(x=c(0.9,0.9,1.1,1.1),y=c(line[2,1],line[2,1],line[2,1],line[2,1])),size=1.2)+geom_path(aes(x=c(0.9,0.9,1.1,1.1),y=c(line[4,1],line[4,1],line[4,1],line[4,1])),size=1.2)+geom_path(aes(x=c(1.9,1.9,2.1,2.1),y=c(line[2,2],line[2,2],line[2,2],line[2,2])),size=1.2)+geom_path(aes(x=c(1.9,1.9,2.1,2.1),y=c(line[4,2],line[4,2],line[4,2],line[4,2])),size=1.2)+geom_path(aes(x=c(1,1),y=c(line[2,1],line[4,1])),size=1.2)+geom_path(aes(x=c(2,2),y=c(line[2,2],line[4,2])),size=1.2)+
scale_colour_manual(name="",values = c("1"="#353F6B","2"="#994642"))+
theme_classic()+theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

So my question: When using jitter function in ggplot2, is it possible to make outliers center, just like the first figure. And what kind of method would you suggest for creating this kind of figure?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data and the code you're using so that we can recreate what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added some sample data and my code.

Answer (score 5):

In ggplot2, the 'jitteriness' is configurable in both directions, e.g.

```
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=hwy, group=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = .2, width = .2))
```

... looks like this:

[image: geom_jitter 0.2]

whereas:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=hwy, group=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = .7, width = .7))
```

... has a more 'shotgun spray' feel to it:

[image: geom_jitter 0.7]

Could you create the effect you're looking for by tweaking the position parameter in geom_jitter?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The outliers in the figure, which I'm trying to recreate, seem to be centered. I have tried the position parameter several times, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This is 6 years over due, but having hit this problem just recently I found an elegant answer using geom_beeswarm in library(geom_beeswarm) and thought I'd post it here.

Reproducing the example above with geom_jitter using mpg is fairly messy:

```
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=hwy, group=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(height = .2, width = .2))
```

[image: Jitter]

Whereas geom_beeswarm makes the jitter points centralised and much clearer:

```
library(beeswarm)
data(mpg)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=cyl, y=hwy, group=factor(cyl))) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_beeswarm()
```

[image: beeswarm]

Answer (score 1):

Seems you only need to adjust jitter.width. I added alpha into the code.  See # <<--

```
gg<- ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x=group,y=value,color=group,fill=group), 
             position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0.1,  # <<- adjusted
                                           dodge.width=0.7), 
             size=4, alpha=0.7)+                              # <<- alpha added
  geom_path(aes(x=c(0.8,1.2),y=c(line[3,1],line[3,1])),size=1)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(1.8,2.2),y=c(line[3,2],line[3,2])),size=1)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(0.9,0.9,1.1,1.1),y=c(line[2,1],line[2,1],line[2,1],line[2,1])),size=1.2)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(0.9,0.9,1.1,1.1),y=c(line[4,1],line[4,1],line[4,1],line[4,1])),size=1.2)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(1.9,1.9,2.1,2.1),y=c(line[2,2],line[2,2],line[2,2],line[2,2])),size=1.2)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(1.9,1.9,2.1,2.1),y=c(line[4,2],line[4,2],line[4,2],line[4,2])),size=1.2)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(1,1),y=c(line[2,1],line[4,1])),size=1.2)+
  geom_path(aes(x=c(2,2),y=c(line[2,2],line[4,2])),size=1.2)+
  scale_colour_manual(name="",values = c("1"="#353F6B","2"="#994642"))+
  theme_classic()+theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

[image]

Just a side note: I'm using ggplot2 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can simply plot your boxplot in ggplot2
and add:
boxplot + geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center',
position=position_dodge(1))

This will create what you are looking for.